# xsetwacom how do I assign script to button

Tags: tablet

How do I set a Wacom button to call a script? eg `xsetwacom --set "pad" Button 2 "~/path/to/script.sh"`

Manjaro linux 4.4.15-3

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20171119123138/http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/index_old.php/howto/xsetwacom), you can only configure a button to emit a key chord event, a mouse button event, or some tablet control functions. So to make a tablet button call a script, you'll need to do it in two steps: configure the button to simulate a key press, and configure that keypress to call a script. Of course, the key press doesn't have to be a key that you have on your keyboard.

You can use `F13`, `F14`, etc. as key names, or use [any valid X keysym](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/List_of_Keysyms_Recognised_by_Xmodmap) — for example, if your script starts a mail reader, use `XF86Mail`.

To bind a key to a command, you can use your desktop environment or window manager's keyboard shortcut functionality, or [xbindkeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/) if you prefer a window manager-agnostic method. For example, put this in your GUI session startup:

```
xsetwacom set pad button2 "key core F13"
```

and this in your `~/.xbindkeysrc`:

```
"~/path/to/script &"
F13
```