# Wacom Intuos: how to map "Touch on|off" to a button?

Tags: tablet, multi-touch, xsetwacom

Is it possible to configure a wacom intuos button with `xsetwacom` in a way that pressing that button enables/disables the touch function?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable and disable touch with the following command:

```
xsetwacom --set 'Touch device name' Touch on
```

To map it to buttons, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/301970/233767). Basically you map the tablet button to a keyboard key and then map that to a command. You can do the first with `xsetwacom` and the latter in the Gnome shortcuts settings.

To toggle the state, you can use `--get` and check if it is on or off. The following uses a hacky `grep` to misuse it as if statement:

```
(xsetwacom get 'Wacom Intuos Pro M (WL) Finger touch' Touch | grep -q off) && (xsetwacom set 'Wacom Intuos Pro M (WL) Finger touch' Touch on) || (xsetwacom set 'Wacom Intuos Pro M (WL) Finger touch' Touch off)
```

Comment: What distribution are you on? I tried but without success, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/756097/additional-udev-rule-to-keep-wacom-stylus-turned-on-while-disabling-touchscreen