# extra udev rule to keep Wacom stylus turned on while disabling Wacom touchscreen?

Tags: udev, wayland, libinput, wacom

I turned off the touchscreen as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927022/how-can-i-disable-touchscreen-while-using-wayland) and [here](https://mastizada.com/blog/disable-touchscreen-in-gnulinux/) on my Lenovo ThinkPad with Debian and [Wayland/libinput](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/what-is-libinput.html).

```
echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5144", ATTR{authorized}="0"' > /etc/udev/rules.d/80-touchscreen.rules
```

Now I need to use the ThinkPad Pen Pro, which is a stylus for the screen/monitor's inbuilt tablet function. The pen is affected by the udev rule. Cancelling the rule makes the pen work but also reactivates touch. The devices have idVendor and idProduct in [common](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039814/how-to-create-a-udev-rule-for-two-devices-with-the-same-manufacturer-id-product).

But are touchscreen and stylus not operating independently, and so shouldn't it be possible to disable the one without the other? (Note, `xinput disable` does not work for some reason, and I don't know what model number goes into [`xsetwacom --set 'model' Touch off`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009818/disable-finger-touch-on-a-touch-screen-laptop-with-a-pen) because `xsetwacom --list devices` returns nothing, so I cannot test it that way.) At least someone reported [touch not working while pen and tablet did function](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963167/wacom-finger-touch-problem-in-16-04-lts).

*Can someone help specify a working [udev rule](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039814/how-to-create-a-udev-rule-for-two-devices-with-the-same-manufacturer-id-product)*, there are [a few](https://wiki.debian.org/udev)? I tried the following but both became deactivated.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5144", ATTR{name}=="Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen", ATTR{authorized}="1"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5144", ATTR{name}=="Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Finger", ATTR{authorized}="0"
```

```
$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=056a Product=5144 Version=0111
N: Name="Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Finger"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-10/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0/0003:056A:5144.0005/input/input32
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse2 event21 
B: PROP=2
B: EV=b
B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=260800000000003

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=056a Product=5144 Version=0111
N: Name="Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-10/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.1/0003:056A:5144.0006/input/input34
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse3 event25 
B: PROP=2
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=1e03 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=1000d000003
B: MSC=1

$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 056a:5144 Wacom Co., Ltd Pen and multitouch sensor

$ inputx --list devices
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:18                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:18              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-stylus:18                        id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-eraser:18                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-cursor:18                        id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-touch:18                         id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]

$ xsetwacom --list devices


$ libwacom-list-local-devices 
# Device node: /dev/input/event25
[Device]
Name=ISDv4 5144
ModelName=
DeviceMatch=usb:056a:5144;
Class=ISDV4
Width=12
Height=7
IntegratedIn=Display;System;
Styli=0x1;0x11;0x19;0x21;0x31;0x39;0x49;0x71;0x221;0x231;0x271;0x421;0x431;0x621;0x631;0x8051;0x805b;0x806b;0x807b;0x826b;0x846b;

[Features]
Reversible=false
Stylus=true
Ring=false
Ring2=false
Touch=true
TouchSwitch=false
# StatusLEDs=
NumStrips=0
Buttons=0

---------------------------------------------------------------

# Device node: /dev/input/event21
[Device]
Name=ISDv4 5144
ModelName=
DeviceMatch=usb:056a:5144;
Class=ISDV4
Width=12
Height=7
IntegratedIn=Display;System;
Styli=0x1;0x11;0x19;0x21;0x31;0x39;0x49;0x71;0x221;0x231;0x271;0x421;0x431;0x621;0x631;0x8051;0x805b;0x806b;0x807b;0x826b;0x846b;

[Features]
Reversible=false
Stylus=true
Ring=false
Ring2=false
Touch=true
TouchSwitch=false
# StatusLEDs=
NumStrips=0
Buttons=0

$ udevadm info /sys/class/input/input32/
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0/0003:056A:5144.0005/input/input32
L: 0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0/0003:056A:5144.0005/input/input32
E: PRODUCT=3/56a/5144/111
E: NAME="Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Finger"
E: PHYS="usb-0000:00:14.0-10/input0"
E: UNIQ=""
E: PROP=2
E: EV=b
E: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0
E: ABS=260800000000003
E: MODALIAS=input:b0003v056Ap5144e0111-e0,1,3,k14A,ra0,1,2F,35,36,39,mlsfw
E: SUBSYSTEM=input
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=6838074
E: ID_INPUT=1
E: ID_INPUT_TOUCHSCREEN=1
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_MODEL=Pen_and_multitouch_sensor
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Pen\x20and\x20multitouch\x20sensor
E: ID_MODEL_ID=5144
E: ID_SERIAL=Wacom_Co._Ltd._Pen_and_multitouch_sensor
E: ID_VENDOR=Wacom_Co._Ltd.
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Wacom\x20Co.\x2cLtd.
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=056a
E: ID_REVISION=0003
E: ID_TYPE=hid
E: ID_USB_MODEL=Pen_and_multitouch_sensor
E: ID_USB_MODEL_ENC=Pen\x20and\x20multitouch\x20sensor
E: ID_USB_MODEL_ID=5144
E: ID_USB_SERIAL=Wacom_Co._Ltd._Pen_and_multitouch_sensor
E: ID_USB_VENDOR=Wacom_Co._Ltd.
E: ID_USB_VENDOR_ENC=Wacom\x20Co.\x2cLtd.
E: ID_USB_VENDOR_ID=056a
E: ID_USB_REVISION=0003
E: ID_USB_TYPE=hid
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030000:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:10:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_10_1_0
E: ID_FOR_SEAT=input-pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_10_1_0
E: TAGS=:seat:
E: CURRENT_TAGS=:seat:

$ udevadm info /sys/class/input/input34
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.1/0003:056A:5144.0006/input/input34
L: 0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.1/0003:056A:5144.0006/input/input34
E: PRODUCT=3/56a/5144/111
E: NAME="Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen"
E: PHYS="usb-0000:00:14.0-10/input1"
E: UNIQ=""
E: PROP=2
E: EV=1b
E: KEY=1e03 0 0 0 0 0
E: ABS=1000d000003
E: MSC=1
E: MODALIAS=input:b0003v056Ap5144e0111-e0,1,3,4,k140,141,149,14A,14B,14C,ra0,1,18,1A,1B,28,m0,lsfw
E: SUBSYSTEM=input
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=6961475
E: ID_INPUT=1
E: ID_INPUT_TABLET=1
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_MODEL=Pen_and_multitouch_sensor
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Pen\x20and\x20multitouch\x20sensor
E: ID_MODEL_ID=5144
E: ID_SERIAL=Wacom_Co._Ltd._Pen_and_multitouch_sensor
E: ID_VENDOR=Wacom_Co._Ltd.
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Wacom\x20Co.\x2cLtd.
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=056a
E: ID_REVISION=0003
E: ID_TYPE=hid
E: ID_USB_MODEL=Pen_and_multitouch_sensor
E: ID_USB_MODEL_ENC=Pen\x20and\x20multitouch\x20sensor
E: ID_USB_MODEL_ID=5144
E: ID_USB_SERIAL=Wacom_Co._Ltd._Pen_and_multitouch_sensor
E: ID_USB_VENDOR=Wacom_Co._Ltd.
E: ID_USB_VENDOR_ENC=Wacom\x20Co.\x2cLtd.
E: ID_USB_VENDOR_ID=056a
E: ID_USB_REVISION=0003
E: ID_USB_TYPE=hid
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030000:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=01
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:10:1.1
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_10_1_1
E: ID_FOR_SEAT=input-pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_10_1_1
E: TAGS=:seat:
E: CURRENT_TAGS=:seat:

$ sudo udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/input/input32


$ sudo udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/input/input34
```